# youtube api v3 search through bash and curl

Tags: linux, bash, curl, youtube

I'm having a problem with the YouTube API. I am trying to make a bash application that will make watching YouTube videos easy on command line in Linux. I'm trying to take some video search results through cURL, but it returns an error: `curl: (16) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: error_code = 1`

the cURL command that I use is:

```
curl "https://ww.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search" -d part="snippet" -d q="kde" -d key="~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
```

And of course I add my YouTube data API key where the `~~~~~~~~` are.
What am I doing wrong?

How can I make it work and return the search attributes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  if you don't understand an answer feel free to ask the person who posted it more questions. You don't have to accept an answer until you understand it, and it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two things that are incorrect in your request:

First, you mistyped "www" and said "ww". That is not a valid URL

Then, `curl`'s "-d" options are for `POST`ing only, not `GET`ting ,at least not by default. You have two options:

1. Add the -G switch to url, which lets curl re-interpret `-d` options as query options:

`curl -G https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search -d part="snippet" -d q="kde" -d key="xxxx"`

2. Rework your url to a typical GET request:

`curl "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=kde&key=XX"`

As a tip, using bash to interpret the resulting json might not be the best way to go. You might want to look into using python, javascript, etc. to run your query and interpret the resulting json.

Comment: OMG, I didn't know that I had my URL mistyped! Thank you very much! my new command is `curl -G "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search" -d part="snippet" -d q="kde" -d key="XXXXXXX"`.
BTW I am going to cut the rest json syntax and keep just the names. That's what I actually need.

Comment: You might want to check out [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for parsing out your json from the commandline.

Comment: 'sed' did the job very well, so there's no need for any json parser. Thank you though, its gonna be useful next time Ill have to do with json.